# How to abbreviate a thesis title on the top of each page

Tags: titles

My thesis title is very long (two lines). LaTeX outputs it ok on the title page, but smashes the whole title together into a single line on subsequent pages, as sort of an automatic heading which bleeds into the margins. What command do I use to include an abbreviated title (i.e. the part before the colon)?

FOR EXAMPLE:
If the main title is

```
This is the first half of my title: this is the second half followed by a colon.
```

The automatic title heading on subsequent pages should be

```
This is the first half of my title.
```

I am using `\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}`. I am also substituting `amsart` with `amsproc` and `amsbook`. The result is the same for all three cases. What should I do?

MWE

```
\documentclass[twoside,onecolumn,11pt,reqno, a4paper]{amsart} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage[color]{showkeys} 
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{Super Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Title}

\begin{document} 
\cleardoublepage 
\tableofcontents 
\cleardoublepage 
\maketitle 
\begin{abstract} 
\end{abstract} 
\pagenumbering{arabic} 
\setcounter{page}{1} 
\section{Introduction} 
\section{Two} 
\subsection{Subsection} 
\subsection{Subsection} 
\subsection{Subsection} 
\subsection{Subsection} 
\section{Three} 
\subsection{Subsection} 
\subsection{Subsection} 
\subsection{Subsection} 
\subsection{Subsection} 
\begin{thebibliography}{3} 
\end{thebibliography} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: \documentclass[twoside,onecolumn,11pt,reqno, a4paper]{amsart} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage[color]{showkeys}
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

Comment: Please do not post your code as comment. Instead, edit your question to add your code there. Also, make sure it's compilable, beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Only load the packages that are relevant.

Comment: I've added a MWE from your comments. Please delete them.

Answer (score 5):

Add the new command `\shortitle` in this way:

```
\documentclass[twoside,onecolumn,11pt,reqno, a4paper]{amsart} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text 

\newcommand\shortitle{This is the first half of my title}

\title{\MakeUppercase{\shortitle}: this is the second half followed by a colon.}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\shortitle.}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @joey [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.